# Multiple Intervals on Page, How to clear interval only on specific element

Tags: element, intervals

I've been having trouble figuring out how to have multiple intervals used on a page. Normally, this wouldn't be a problem but I'm working to create a dynamic countdown script which uses data submitted by the user and have to abide by a few rules:

1. I need the interval only to clear specifically for given element.
2. I only need the interval to clear if there currently is an interval set in that specific element.

My idea was to count each interval and assign the number instance to each one. So something like this :

```
function(element, data, api) {

let intervalIds = [];

for (var i=0; i < intervalIds.length; i++){
}

intervalIds.push(setInterval(function(){

console.log(intervalIds[i]);

clearInterval(intervalIds[i]-1);

//timecalculations after

}, 1000 )); 
}
```

This worked at first, however when I refresh the page with multiple intervals, but after I refresh the page there is only one interval.

1. If the element ID is the same and a interval has been set for this element then clear the previous interval
2. If the element ID is different just simply start a new interval

P.S with the software I'm using I can access the element id using data.elementId. ex: if (data.elementId == data.elementId) { do stuff }

Comment: I have to admit, I'm a little confused by the code sample. It looks like `intervalIds` would be set to an empty array every time the function is executed and the `for` loop wouldn't do anything since `intervalIds` would have a length of 0. This would also leave `i` equal to 0.
So when the interval is pushed into `intervalIds` and it executes it would console log the only item in the array then try to clear an interval with the ID stored at position 0 in `intervalIds` but minus 1. So if the ID is 33 it would try to clear interval ID 32, which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: @hradac, well now that you mention it, that would explain why the process works as I place the widgets on the page, but when you refresh the page, the widget breaks.

Edit: if I set the initial count to let intervalIds = [0]; instead would this help? Essentially what I'm trying to do is count the number of times an interval is set on the page.  I may need to review how to do this using arrays and for loops. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer to this riddle.

You would need to create a dynamic variable. To do this you would either need to use eval() or assign the variable to the window scope. Then assign the interval to that variable.

Luckily, the software I work with assigns a unique Id to each element added to the page. So I can use this unique Id to assign it to the variable to create the dynamic va

For example:

```
//unique id
var dynamicIntervalID  = $(element).attr('id');
//clear interval if one exists
if (window["intervalIds"+dynamicIntervalID])clearInterval(window["intervalIds"+dynamicIntervalID]) 

//assign unique element id to interval 
window["intervalIds"+dynamicIntervalID] = setInterval(function(){
 ...code here..
 }, 1000 );
```

Hope this helps.